# Sending an automated SMS message when a button is clicked

Tags: java, android, text, sms, message

I am building an app that needs to send out a predefined text message on the click of a button (imagine a set of three buttons, each sending out a different line of text that has already been defined by the programmer).

I have no experience using the text features and I would like some guidance on how this could be done. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible ways to send SMS using Android :

**SmsManager API**

```
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "your message goes here", null, null);
```

**Built-in SMS application**

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "default content"); 
    sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Of course, both need SEND_SMS permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

You can take reference of this tutorial : http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);
```

and remember your permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll give this a try once i've got a working sim card as i'm unable to get an emulator working at the moment